# RelativeLayout width and height fill_parent doesn't work

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout

This is my layout which is an info window, and its shown where there is new info to show to the user.

The layout should take the whole screen with some transparent background color, and a small text layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- info fragment - used by the fragment to provide info on a specific fragment -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.coapps.pico"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_dark_green" >

    //this is the only layout i see in the result. not it's parent's layout...
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_info_relativelayout_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_info_window"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp" >

            <!-- The info textView -->

            <com.coapps.pico.NillanTextView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_info_textview_info"
                style="@style/text_shadow_black"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Some Text "
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:isBold="true" />
        </ScrollView>
        <!-- Tap to close -->

        <com.coapps.pico.NillanTextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_info_textview_tap_to_close"
            style="@style/text_shadow_black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/button_tap_to_close"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:isBold="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm adding this layout to another ViewGroup like this:

```
/**
 * Show the info window
 */
public void show()
{
    //if the window is not visible
    if (!isVisible())
        //add window's view
        rootView.addView(infoWindowView);
}
```

this code add the info window into its root view container in the last index.

in result i only see the second RelativeLayout which contains the text but i don't see its parent root layout which supposed to be transparent...

Any ideas why ?

**Update:**
This is my container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is the main layout of the application -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_basic_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try change

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_info_relativelayout_info"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_info_window"
        android:clickable="true" >
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_info_relativelayout_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_info_window"
        android:clickable="true" >
```

Anyway, why the need of nested `RelativeLayout` ?

I see how do you add the view, so try also this:

```
infoWindowView.setLayoutParams(
       new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
rootView.addView(infoWindowView);
```

Comment: since i need the first(root) layout to fill the whole screen with a transparent color to get the focus to the second relative layout..

Comment: it doesn't seems to work... any even so - i don't really understand why should it work ? how come that my root layout width and height's fill_parent doesn't working ? it never happened before

Comment: Is it the content of a compound custom view? What is the container?

Comment: I've added the container.. what do you mean by compound custom view?

Comment: there are no custom views.. the only thing is that my NillanTextView already has a TypeFace font set because i can't do it in the XML

Comment: Ok try to set LayoutParams as described above

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with a view in Relative layout that was dependent on the Relative layout's size.
I solved this problem problematically by updating the inner view size

```
private void update viewSize()
if(rootContainer == null || rootContainer.getLayoutParams() == null)
return;
rootContainer.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ScalingUtil.getScreenSize().getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams oldLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.deals_card_center_bg).getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(rootContainer.getMeasuredWidth(), rootContainer.getMeasuredHeight());
    layoutParams.setMargins(oldLayoutParams.leftMargin, oldLayoutParams.topMargin, oldLayoutParams.rightMargin, oldLayoutParams.bottomMargin);

    rootContainer.findViewById(R.id.deals_card_center_bg).setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to not have the parent expand

Instead of `match_parent` on the child, align it to the sibling that dictates the height.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_that_should_match_its_parents_height"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/element_that_dictates_height" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/element_that_dictates_height"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Worked for me, hope it helps. The second `View` is usually some `ViewGroup`, that varies in height.